# Вывод потока в консоль

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Приветствую!
Запускаю в программе команду ipconfig через cmd:

```
public void adapterConfig(){
    try {
        // Execute command
        String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe","/C","start","ipconfig"};
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}
```

Нужно результат команды вывести для чтения (хотя бы в консоль). Подскажите, пожалуйста!
Вывод (не смейтесь, я только учусь:-) ):
            OutputStream stream = child.getOutputStream();
            System.out.print(stream.toString());
    на выходе дает:
    java.io.BufferedOutputStream@62610b

А нужен именно вывод результата команды ipconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извините винды нету проверить не смог но уверен что будет работать, предыдущий ответ делает тоже самое но для дочернего запущеного приложения не получит консольный вывод вроде))

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String line;
    String[] command = new String[] { "ipconfig" };
    Process p;
    try
    {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Log.e(TAG,e.toString(),e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий способ:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

**UPD#1**: Попробуйте изменить строку с командой:

```
 String command = "cmd /c ipconfig";
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!
К сожалению, не помогло. В консоли пусто.